sum $\sum (2^{a_1-1}-1)...(2^{a_k-1}-1)$
This problem is referring to Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics Volume 1 Ex35 g)
Express the sum of following as a Fibonacci number $$\sum (2^{a_1-1}-1)...(2^{a_k-1}-1)$$
The sum ranges over all integers compositions of n.
In the answer he provided(were actually Gessel's answers): Given a composition $(a_1, . . . , a_k)$ of $n$, replace each part $a_i$ with a composition
$\alpha_i$ of $2ai$ into parts 1 and 2, such that $\alpha_i$ begins with a 1, ends in a 2, and for all $j$ the 2j-th 1 in α is followed by a 1, unless this 2j-th 1 is the last 1 in α. For instance, the part $a_i$ = 4 can be replaced by any of the seven compositions 1111112, 111122, 111212, 11222, 121112, 12122, 12212. It can be checked that (i) every composition of $2n$ into parts 1 and 2, beginning with 1 and ending with 2, occurs exactly once by applying this procedure to all compositions of n, and (ii) the number of compositions that can replace ai is $2^{a_i−1} − 1$.
I can't see the bijection at all, since they are subjected to plenty of constraints. Gessel made these observations based on factoring of free monoids. Should explaining in this context should make the interpretation easier?
Edit 1: Using anon's hint I got the following proof to the number of compositions of 2n is $2^{n-1}-1$, the proof is following
Now consider irreducible good compositions of 2n, and consider a random irreducible good composition of 2(n+1). If the second to last digit of that good comp is 2, then removing the last 2 would give a good comp of 2n. So for all good comp of 2(n+1) whose second digit is 2, there is as many as the good comps of 2n, which is $2^{n}-1$
Now if the second to last digit is a 1. Then it is equivalent to find all composition of 2n who starts with a 1 and ends with a 1. And every 2jth 1 must be followed by a 1(because we already have the last 1 in the end). So each time we either add a "11" or "2" because the first 1 in "11" will always be the 2jth 1. So its $2^n$
Adding together gives the required result.

The framing above makes the solution more mysterious than it needs to be. Note that while I'll write this in terms of compositions, if your brain runs on algebra, you can describe this in terms of monoids instead. However, you'll basically go through all the same steps in the solution, just with different notation.
Call a composition "good" if it begins with 1, ends with 2, and has even length. Call a good composition "irreducible" if it cannot be written by concatenating two good compositions. Note that the irreducible good compositions are exactly those described in your formulation of the solution.
The number of good compositions of $2n$ is $F_{2n-2}$.
Now prove:
Lemma 1 Every good composition can written as a concatenation of irreducible good compositions in exactly one way. (Suggested method to make it obvious: if there are two distinct decompositions into irreducibles, look at the first block in which they differ, and derive a contradiction.)
Lemma 2 There are $2^{n-1}-1$ irreducible good compositions of $2n$. (Suggested method: Observe that an irreducible good composition must match Stanley's description, or to put it more concisely, must match the regular expression $1(11|2)*122*$. Condition on the number of trailing $2$s.)

I'll take a look into regular expression to see if I can produce a combinatorial proof.

Ok I think I get some sort of proof to lemma 2. If my proof is wrong/iffy at some point please point it out. I don't think the your regular expression is correct... because 12121212 is a counter example that does not follow your pattern. But it is pretty useful. Now consider irreducible good compositions of 2n, and consider a random irreducible good composition of 2(n+1). If the second to last digit of that good comp is 2, then removing the last 2 would give a good comp of 2n. So for all good comp of 2(n+1) whose second digit is 2, there is as many as the good comps of 2n.

I will leave the part of the second to last digit of a good comp of 2(n+1) case to an edit in my question, because I need some examples, which would make this comment too long

"12121212 is a counter example that does not follow your pattern."
No, that's not a counterexample. It is not an irreducible good composition, because it can be reduced to (1212)(1212).

OHHHHHHHH, I think I misunderstood your explanation and Stanley's explanation. Just to confirm, the 2jth 1 must be followed by a 1. Are we talking about the 2jth position in the composition is a 1, or are we talking about the 2jth 1, excluding the 2s, is a 1?

OHHHHHHH, Ok I think I got it. I misunderstood the question. My 12121212 is false, even in Stanley's explanation. because the 2jth 1 isn't even followed by a 1. (In my previous understanding, I thought: if the 2jth position in the whole composition is a 1, then it must be followed with a 1...) I will edit my post.

One more thing, can you show me combinatorially how you get that Fibonacci number in the end?

The number of compositions of $k$ into 1s and 2s is $F_{k+1}$. This is easily proved from the Fibonacci recurrence (condition on the first part).
If we restrict to good compositions and $k = 2n$, the first part must be 1 and the last part must be 2, but the remaining parts can be any composition of $2n-3$ into 1s and 2s. So there are $F_{2n-2}$ good compositions of $2n$.
